# Magento non-CMS page showing 404 error

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I am very new to Magento and have inherited a shop that has been built outside CMS. The page was hard coded for 3 products, and included the cart, shipping and payment in a single page. I need to enable more products (which I have done), enable a product details page, a separate shopping cart and a separate shipping and payment page.

The urls include language and location information as I run three shops. So, I have www.company.com/en/shop/eu/products and this shows me the correct page. I would like to have www.company.com/en/shop/eu/detail to show one product in detail.

To this end, I have created `/shop/app/code/local/Company/Detail` with a simple `IndexController.php` and `config.xml`. I have also created `/shop/app/design/frontend/company/detail` and have content.phtml there. I also have `/shop/app/etc/modules/Company_Detail.xml`. I also have placed the content.phtml in `/shop/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/detail/` as well. I was following this tutorial.... http://www.human-element.com/Blog/ArticleDetailsPage/tabid/91/ArticleID/69/Magento-Non-CMS-Pages-Creating-Pages-Via-Frontend-Routers.aspx

URL rewrite is enabled and installed. Everything is re-indexed and all caches flushed. Any more pointers?

STACK TRACE

0 include() called at [/var/www/co/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:235]

1 Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView(frontend/changers/changers/template/page/404.phtml) called at [/var/www/co/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:266]

2 Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView() called at [/var/www/co/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:280]

3 Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml() called at [/var/www/co/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:758]

4 Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml() called at [/var/www/co/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:529]

5 Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput() called at [/var/www/changers/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:391]

6 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout() called at [/var/www/changers/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php:91]

7 Mage_Cms_IndexController->defaultNoRouteAction() called at [/var/www/co/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:420]

8 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch(defaultNoRoute) called at [/var/www/co/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php:253]

9 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http Object ([] => /detail,[] => ,[] => /detail,[] => ,[] => ,[] => Array (),[] => cms,[] => Array ([api] => ,[xmlconnect] => ),[] => Mage_Cms,[] => ,[] => Array ([params] => Array (),[action_name] => noRoute,[controller_name] => index,[module_name] => cms),[] => Array ([0] => _GET,[1] => _POST),[] => /en/shop/eu/detail,[] => /en/shop,[] => ,[] => /detail,[] => Array (),[] => ,[] => Array (),[] => 1,[] => cms,[] => module,[] => index,[] => controller,[] => defaultNoRoute,[] => action)) called at [/var/www/changers/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:176]

10 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() called at [/var/www/co/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:340]

11 Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array ([scope_code] => ,[scope_type] => store,[options] => Array ())) called at [/var/www/co/shop/app/Mage.php:627]

12 Mage::run(, store) called at [/var/www/co/shop/index.php:80]

Answer (score 0):

The URL rewrites would go in the shop/app/code/local/Company/Detail/etc/config.xml file, where you can use the router function in xml in the following fashion :

```
    <routers>
  <detail>
    <use>standard</use>
      <args>
        <module>Company_Detail</module>
        <frontName>detail</frontName>
      </args>
  </detail>
</routers>
```

Comment: Thanks, however this is as in my config.xml file. I also tried <routers><company_detail> as some examples had.